# Conocer la cantidad de vocales de una frase (C#)

Tags: c#, foreach

Tengo una duda sobre una codificación que encontré en internet y que si funciona:

```
            string nombre;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa tu nombre: ");
            nombre = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            int a = 0;
            int e = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int o = 0;
            int u = 0;

            foreach (char c in nombre) //Convierte de "string" a "char"
            {
                if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
                {
                    a++;
                }
                else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                {
                    e++;
                }
                else if (c == 'i' || c == 'I')
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O')
                {
                    o++;
                }
                else if (c == 'u' || c == 'U')
                {
                    u++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("El total de Aa es de: " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("El total de Ee es de: " + e);
            Console.WriteLine("El total de Ii es de: " + i);
            Console.WriteLine("El total de Oo es de: " + o);
            Console.WriteLine("El total de Uu es de: " + u);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Veo que en el foreach no tiene problema de leer los caracteres del string, pero mi duda era del por que no funciona con un **array tipo string**, en si el foreach menciona que hay un error ya que no se puede convertir de **string** a **char**, si se que es una manera un poco más extraña de resolverlo, pero solo tenia esa duda mientras codificaba:

```
            int cantidadNombres;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de nombres y apellidos que tiene: ");
            cantidadNombres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] nombres = new string[cantidadNombres];

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadNombres; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre " + (i + 1));
                nombres[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            int total = 0;
            int cantidadA = 0;
            int cantidadE = 0;
            int cantidadI = 0;
            int cantidadO = 0;
            int cantidadU = 0;

            foreach (char item in nombres) //Aquí da error "No se puede convertir de "string" a "char"
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
```

Necesariamente debo de ocupar el **foreach** para resolver este problema ya que el enunciado lo menciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `nombres` es un array de `string[]` y cuando haces `foreach (char item in nombres)` la variable `item` no es de tipo `char`, es de tipo `string`, por eso te da el error.

- Un `foreach` sobre un **array de strings**(`string[]`) te va a dar en
  cada iteración un elemento del array, es decir, uno de los `string`
  que guarda. En tu caso particular sería un `nombre`.
- Un `foreach` sobre un `string` te va a dar en cada iteración cada
  letra del `string`, es decir, te devuelve un `char` en cada
  iteración.

La clave está en diferenciar el **tipo de datos** sobre el cual estás iterando. Si solo ocupas usar `foreach` para la resolución del ejercicio, anida dos `foreach`. Uno para que itere sobre el array, y otro que itere sobre las letras.

Contando las vocales de todos los nombres quedaría así:

```
int cantidadNombres;
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de nombres y apellidos que tiene: ");
cantidadNombres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string[] nombres = new string[cantidadNombres];

for (int i = 0; i < cantidadNombres; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre " + (i + 1));
    nombres[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}

int total = 0;
int cantidadA = 0;
int cantidadE = 0;
int cantidadI = 0;
int cantidadO = 0;
int cantidadU = 0;

foreach (string nombre in nombres)
{
    foreach (char c in nombre) //Convierte de "string" a "char"
    {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
        {
            cantidadA++;
        }
        else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
        {
            cantidadE++;
        }
        else if (c == 'i' || c == 'I')
        {
            cantidadI++;
        }
        else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O')
        {
            cantidadO++;
        }
        else if (c == 'u' || c == 'U')
        {
            cantidadU++;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("El total de Aa es de: " + cantidadA);
Console.WriteLine("El total de Ee es de: " + cantidadE);
Console.WriteLine("El total de Ii es de: " + cantidadI);
Console.WriteLine("El total de Oo es de: " + cantidadO);
Console.WriteLine("El total de Uu es de: " + cantidadU);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Puedes ejecutar este programa online en [este enlace](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Kd4__1Eko):

Answer (score 1):

Antes obtenías el total de vocales de un solo nombre, pero al emplear un arreglo de nombres, obtendrás el total de vocales de varios nombres, por lo que deberás hacer un primer **foreach** para recorrer el arreglo de nombres, y por cada nombre hacer un segundo **foreach** que recorra todas las letras de ese nombre y cuente las vocales:

```
int cantidadNombres;
int[] totalVocales = new int[5];

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de nombres y apellidos que tiene: ");
cantidadNombres = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string[] nombres = new string[cantidadNombres];

for (int i = 0; i < cantidadNombres; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre " + (i + 1));
    nombres[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}

foreach (var nombre in nombres)
{
   foreach (var n in nombre.ToLower())
   {
      if (n == 'a')
      {
         totalVocales[0]++;
      }
      else if (n == 'e')
      {
         totalVocales[1]++;
      }
      else if (n == 'i')
      {
         totalVocales[2]++;
      }
      else if (n == 'o')
      {
         totalVocales[3]++;
      }
      else if (n == 'u')
      {
         totalVocales[4]++;
      }
   }
   
   Console.WriteLine("El total de A/a es de: " + totalVocales[0]);
   Console.WriteLine("El total de E/e es de: " + totalVocales[1]);
   Console.WriteLine("El total de I/i es de: " + totalVocales[2]);
   Console.WriteLine("El total de O/o es de: " + totalVocales[3]);
   Console.WriteLine("El total de U/u es de: " + totalVocales[4]);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Para reducir código puedes emplear un arreglo de enteros donde la primera posición represente las letras **'A'**, **'a'**, la segunda posición las letras **'E'**, **'e'**, y así con el resto de las vocales, es decir cada posición del arreglo representa el total de una vocal.

Llenamos el arreglo de nombres tal como haces, y después entonces haríamos dos **foreach** uno para recorrer el arreglo de nombres y otro para recorrer cada letra de ese nombre. A medida que vayamos recorriendo cada letra del nombre preguntamos si es una vocal, y de serlo incrementamos la posición correspondiente del **arreglo totalVocales**. Por último imprimimos el total por cada vocal.

**Nota:** Este código puede reducirse mucho más con el empleo de una estructura de datos llamadas **Diccionario**, pero ese estudio te lo dejo a ti.